# BB10 Date picker title for HTML input type=date tag

Tags: html, cordova, datepicker, blackberry-10

I've got an HTML5-based mobile app running on a variety of devices, including the BB10 (and others, but I mostly care about the BB10 for this question).

One of the very specific defects raised by the QA tester team relates to date pickers.  We're using simple input fields (type=date), and when the user taps in field, the OS brings up the native date picker.  The defect is a complaint about the title on that date picker: currently, it uses a bland title ("Date"), and the QA folk and business unit want a more descriptive title.

My question is: can anything change that title?  Here's my current HTML snippet:

```
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
  <div id="fromDateText">From Date:</div>
  <input type="date" id="fromDate" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="From Date" />
</div>
```

Does the BB10 WebView attempt to use any information in the HTML to determine the picker title? Can I use a title attribute or anything like that to change the title?  Or it just always going to say "Date"?

**Update:** Hm. I've tried using a label around the text (hoping that the widget would pick that up) and I even tried (without much hope) putting a title attribute on the input field. In both cases, the datepicker kept the generic "Date" title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  The title of the DatePicker dialog cannot be customized from its default value.

I just spoke to Mike and Chris from the BlackBerry browser dev team who confirmed the following:

> "We perform localization on behalf of the web developer. So it's
>   "Date" in English but translated to whatever locale the user agent has
>   set."

Comment: Thanks for confirming this.